# Error with PHP SOAP and Magento WebService

Tags: php, magento, soap, centos

I have a cloud server with CentOS 6, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4 and i have one site with Magento.
And i try to use a Magento WebService and return this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://******.com/dev/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://******.com/dev/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"
```

I search here and in google, and i try many changes in php.ini, but in all cases i don't have success.

I read in some cases this is a problem in server side, for bad configuration.

Note¹: SOAP is installed in server, in phpinfo() SOAP is enabled.

Note²: On another server was working normally.

Anyone have any ideia how to solve this?

Edit: The server use WHM/CPanel and i use EasyApache for install Apache, PHP. And use default configuration.

Edit2: This is just a simple sample code that uses the SOAP and error it returns:

Code: (first line of this code is a line 9, and line 13 is "$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v1);")

```
<?php
    $api_url_v1 = "http://site.com/dev/api/soap/?wsdl=1";
    $username = '*********';
    $password = '*********';
    $cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v1);
    //retreive session id from login
    $session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);
    //call customer.list method
    $result = $cli->call($session_id, 'customer.list', array(array()));
?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://site.com/dev/api/soap/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://site.com/dev/api/soap/?wsdl=1" in /home/******/public_html/test_soap.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/******/public_html/test_soap.php(13): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://site...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/******/public_html/test_soap.php on line 13
```

Comment: Is CURL installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, "cURL support:enabled". ;)

Comment: I no have SSL Certificate for use https, but openssl is enabled in PHP. "OpenSSL support:enabled"

Comment: Please add ALL necessary informations like code listing. As you can see two errors points to two different things.

Comment: Kamil the first error is caused when I use a third party API, so do not have access to the code, but I know that it is a functional code was running on shared hosting that I used previously. The second code I copied one of the posts here "stackoverflow" (if I remember correctly) to test the functioning of SOAP and returned this error that put. And the two errors are equal, the only difference is that in the second it shows the file that caused the error. Already the first shows probably not by choice of developers.

Answer (score 0):

try to fetch the wsdl via webbrowser. if this does not work then you have an error in url. try www version of the urls, check for bad rewrites, check htaccess. you dont need https!

Comment: When I use the www.site.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1 it redirects to the homepage. But when I use just site.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1 it redirects to the XML file. But I'm using the API without the www.